# Using gawk to add a value separated by a comma

Tags: shell, awk

I have a txt file that looks like this.

```
this-is-name-1
this-is-name-2
...
```

I am trying to add a `,0` at the end of a certain line using gawk,
`gawk -i inplace -v n=',0' -v s='this-is-name-1' '$1 == s { $2 = n } 1' file`
But as you can see there is a space in-between.

```
this-is-name-1 ,0
this-is-name-2
...
```

Whats the right gawk syntax so there is no space, so it like this instead

```
this-is-name-1,0
this-is-name-2
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$2 = n` to `$0 = $0 n`. Your current code is adding a 2nd field so awk has to add a separator between  the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Use comma as the *output* field separator:

```sh
gawk -i inplace -v OFS=',' -v n='0' -v s='this-is-name-1' '$1 == s { $2 = n } 1' file
# ..............^^^^^^^^^^.......^ (no comma here)
```